# Looking for the most profitable range (mathematical names: "maximum subarray problem" or "maximum consecutive subsequence sum")

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sequence, cumulative-sum, sumifs

To be able to find the most profitable range, I add the lowest value I want to the highest value I want, with that I create a table like this example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17zpapBeC5wYxyU6SjbqcbnV4_QP4gooxj0PxdCywDk0/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Cell's formulas examples:

Between `0` and `0`:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER($B$1:$B,($A$1:$A<=D2)*($A$1:$A>=$E$1))))
```

Between `5` and `10`:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER($B$1:$B,($A$1:$A<=D12)*($A$1:$A>=$J$1))))
```

```
=MAX(E2:O12)
Max Profit = £185.00

=INDEX(A1:O1,ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(IF(E2:O12=MAX(E2:O12),COLUMN(E2:O12)))))
Value Min for Max Profit = 4

=INDEX(D1:D12,ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(IF(E2:O12=MAX(E2:O12),ROW(E2:O12)))))
Value Max for Max Profit = 10
```

When there are hundreds of values¹ in `A` and `B`, this table gets very big and heavy, even causing crashes like my current original data spreadsheet.

Is there any way using a only one formula or script code to found `Max Profit | Value Min for Max Profit | Value Max for Max Profit` without doing each range one by one needing to use thousands of cells each with a specific formula?

Notes:

hundreds of values¹ → my original spreadsheet currently contains `1471` rows of data in `A` with the results in `B`. So to be able to do this analysis, I need to put `2,163,841` formulas like `=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER($B$1:$B,($A$1:$A<=D2)*($A$1:$A>=$E$1))))` in the cells to create the table and find the most profitable range.

Comment: "hundreds" like "few hundreds" or like "even thousands" ?

Comment: Hi @player0  my original spreadsheet currently contains ```1471``` rows of data in ```A``` with the results in ```B```. So to be able to do this analysis, I need to put ```2,163,841``` formulas like ```=INDEX(A1:O1,,ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(IF(E2:O12=MAX(E2:O12),COLUMN(E2:O12)))))``` in the cells to create the table and find the most profitable range.

Comment: @player0 In fact, the ```2,163,841``` formulas if I need to put in cell's would be like this one: ```=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER($B$1:$B,($A$1:$A<=D2)*($A$1:$A>=$E$1))))```, the one I put in the previous comment is the formula just to find the ```Value Min for Max Profit```. Sorry for the wrong info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

max:

```
=INDEX(MAX(IF(SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1)>=SEQUENCE(1, MAX(A:A)+1), 
 SUMIF(SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1), "<="&SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1), B:B)* 
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(A:A)+1, 1, )-QUERY(QUERY(
 (SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1)<SEQUENCE(1, MAX(A:A)+1))*B1:B, 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "sum(Col"&SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1)&")")), 
 "offset 1", ), )))
```

[image]

---

value min:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(MAX(IF(SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1)>=SEQUENCE(1, MAX(A:A)+1), 
 SUMIF(SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1), "<="&SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1), B:B)* 
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(A:A)+1, 1, )-QUERY(QUERY(
 (SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1)<SEQUENCE(1, MAX(A:A)+1))*B1:B, 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "sum(Col"&SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1)&")")), 
 "offset 1", )+(SEQUENCE(1, MAX(A:A)+1)*10^-10)&9, )*1)&"", "0(\d+)9$")-1)
```

value max:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(MAX(IF(SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1)>=SEQUENCE(1, MAX(A:A)+1), 
 SUMIF(SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1), "<="&SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1), B:B)* 
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(A:A)+1, 1, )-QUERY(QUERY(
 (SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1)<SEQUENCE(1, MAX(A:A)+1))*B1:B, 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "sum(Col"&SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1)&")")), 
 "offset 1", )+(SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1)*10^-10)&9, )*1)&"", "0(\d+)9$")-1)
```

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, UNIQUE(FLATTEN(
 IF(IF(SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1)>=SEQUENCE(1, MAX(A:A)+1), 
 SUMIF(SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1), "<="&SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1), B:B)* 
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(A:A)+1, 1, )-QUERY(QUERY(
 (SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1)<SEQUENCE(1, MAX(A:A)+1))*B1:B, 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "sum(Col"&SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1)&")")), 
 "offset 1", ), )=MAX(IF(SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1)>=SEQUENCE(1, MAX(A:A)+1), 
 SUMIF(SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1), "<="&SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1), B:B)* 
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(A:A)+1, 1, )-QUERY(QUERY(
 (SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1)<SEQUENCE(1, MAX(A:A)+1))*B1:B, 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "sum(Col"&SEQUENCE(MAX(A:A)+1)&")")), 
 "offset 1", ), )), SEQUENCE(1, MAX(A:A)+1, 0), )))))
```

[image]

Comment: solutions not tested on larger datasets - it may cause some BSOD lol

Comment: hello @player0 , I did some tests and found that the method finds some flaws, for example, when some values are zero, it delivers a minimum value greater than the maximum value and if any of the values in B is too high, such as ```100000``` it generates an error ```The value "0(\d+)9$" of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 does not match the text of the value "105000.9" of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1.``` I left the example in the spreadsheet in case you can take a look. Thank you!

Comment: @BrondbyIF answer updated. see your sheet

Comment: Amazing, I followed your movements in the spreadsheet in real time, it is very interesting to follow the work of someone with such knowledge capacity! Thank you very much again, and if I notice any error, I'll let you know so that we can remove any obstacles from the case.